# Get index of parent div based on child class

Tags: jquery

```
  var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().index(".fc-row.fc-week.fc-widget-content");
```

I did this for get index for parent. can there have any other option to write this code

Comment: $.parents("#yourid") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `parent()` function so many times, you could just use `closest()` with a selector for the container containing `".fc-row.fc-week.fc-widget-content"` like

```
var index = $(this).closest('someselectorhere').index(".fc-row.fc-week.fc-widget-content");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use

```
var index = $(this).parents(".fc-row.fc-week.fc-widget-content");
```